# IIS Express vs Default IIS that comes with Windows 7

Tags: iis, iis-express

I am new to the world of IIS and I wanted to know the following...

I have heard about IIS Express. I run Windows 7 Ultimate and have installed the IIS that comes packaged with Windows 7.

As a developer, is there any major benefit for me if I install IIS Express over the default IIS that comes with Windows 7 for .Net Web projects?

Comment: One benefit of IIS Express that doesn't seem to have been mentioned here is it supports Visual Studio's *Edit and Continue* debugging functionality.

Comment: And there's more [info on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156004.aspx).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Here are the differences from http://www.mywindowsclub.com/resources/3302-Key-differences-between-IIS-IIS-Developer.aspx.

If you already have IIS installed - its a better product.  IIS express would only be used by people who don't have access to IIS or want something that is lighter than IIS but more like IIS than Cassini.

- **Integrated with OS**

  - IIS 7 ships with the operating system and is tightly integrated to Windows.
  - IIS developer express is a separate downloadable tool
- **Targetted users**

  - IIS 7 is for both developers as well as for production purposes.
  - IIS developer express can be used only for development purposes and not for production.
- **Supported Windows editions**

  - IIS 7 will work only on Windows Vista and newer editions of Windows. In case of server OS, IIS 7 will work only on Windows 2008.
  - IIS developer edition will work even on older version - starting from Windows XP and newer.
- **Process model and activation**

  - In IIS 7, the worker thread is automatically launched and managed by Windows Process Activation Service.
  - In case of IIS Express, user has to handle this.
- **FTP support**

  - IIS developer express does not support FTP while IIS 7 supports it.
- **WCF support**

  - IIS Developer express supports only WCF over HTTP.
  - IIS 7 supports WCF including over TCP, Named Pipes, and MSMQ.
- **Multi developer support**

  - IIS 7 is a single user application.
  - IIS Developer express supports multi developer environment. Configuration files, settings, and Web content are maintained on a per-user basis.
- **Visual Studio integration**

  - All editions and versions of Visual Studio have built-in support for IIS 7.
  - Only VS 2010 and future versions will have built-in support for IIS developer express.
- **Runtime extensions**

  - IIS developer has support for URL Rewrite and FastCGI.
  - Webmatrix offers support for SEO, database management and Web Deployment. Other extensions that are offered with IIS are not yet tested with IIS Developer express.
- **Management Tools**

  - IIS 7 is managed using the IIS Manager.
  - IIS Developer express can be managed using Webmatrix. Also, the express edition has support through system tray.
- **Port used by IIS**

  - The default website comes with IIS 7 listens to port 80.
  - The default website part of IIS developer express listens to port 8080 to avoid conflicts with IIS 7 when they are running side by side.

Comment: small correction... VS 2010 SP1 and future VS versions have built-in IIS Express support.

Comment: While this answer points it out very well, here is the [Microsoft page about IIS 7 vs. IIS Express 7.5](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview).

Comment: Except the fact that [IIS Express can also have an IIS Manager style management console](https://jexus.codeplex.com/releases/view/138373), this answer provides most information a developer needs.

Comment: Some newer points: IIS Express now have version 8 and 10 available, allowing by example to test with an IIS 8 or 10 lookalike on a windows seven desktop. But IIS hotfixes like [IIS compression & vary header field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2877816) are lacking for IIS Express.

Answer (score 30):

**From Scott Gu's [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) on IIS Express:**

**Why Not IIS**

> The downside with using the IIS option today, though, is that some
>   companies don’t allow full web-servers to be installed on developer
>   machines. IIS also requires administrator account access to setup and
>   debug projects.  Different versions of Windows also support different
>   versions of IIS.  For example, if you are running on Windows XP you
>   have to use the IIS 5.1 web-server that comes with it – which doesn’t
>   support all the new features of IIS 7.x.  Configuring a web project
>   within VS to use IIS also requires some extra installation and
>   configuration steps.

**Why IIS Express**

> It’s lightweight and easy to install (less than 10Mb download and a
>   super quick install) It does not require an administrator account to
>   run/debug applications from Visual Studio It enables a full web-server
>   feature set – including SSL, URL Rewrite, Media Support, and all other
>   IIS 7.x modules It supports and enables the same extensibility model
>   and web.config file settings that IIS 7.x support It can be installed
>   side-by-side with the full IIS web server as well as the ASP.NET
>   Development Server (they do not conflict at all) It works on Windows
>   XP and higher operating systems – giving you a full IIS 7.x developer
>   feature-set on all OS platforms IIS Express (like the ASP.NET
>   Development Server) can be quickly launched to run a site from a
>   directory on disk.  It does not require any registration/configuration
>   steps. This makes it really easy to launch and run for development
>   scenarios.

Comment: Thanks Ken for the answer, but in my scenario where I already have IIS with Windows 7 Ultimate installed, ie - I do not have the administrator lock down problem. Is there any other major benefit of IIS Express over the default one that you can install in Win7 Ultimate.

Comment: Not really. Having local admin is a privilege.  Enterprises don't like granting local admin, as it can result in the installation of unlicensed tools, introduction of viruses and overriding of default security policies. IIS Express allows non local admins to use a subset of IIS and still debug without having any escalated privileges. No Run As Administrator required.

Comment: @KenBurkhardt Do you know if it's possible to enable edit and continue on a local IIS instance? It's possible in the Express version, which is lighter than the local ones, so it makes sense to think the *full* version would be able to do everything the *express* version can do, on top of the additional features.

Comment: @HéctorÁlvarez Edit and Continue can be enabled in Windows 10. See my answer to your question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786080/edit-and-continue-using-a-local-iis

Answer (score 11):

After a couple of hours i found one significant reason to use Express over Local IIS : "Edit and Continue" does not work on local IIS.

Comment: It can work under Windows 10, when you set environment variable for your app pool. For more details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50509545/1903736

Comment: This is the first answer that gave me the brass tacks that I needed.  Thanks