# installing php mysql installation on windows 7 with iis

Tags: php, mysql, installation

im installing WordPress on my local host for development purpose.
i have installed php and verified it is working using

```
phpinfo();
```

I have also installed MySQL on my machine.
I have unmarked MySQL.dll 
Unmarked MySQL.dll extension on my PHP.INI file and restarted IIS.

now once i go to the WordPress installation address im getting :

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
```

is there another settings im forgetting to deal with ?

Comment: try http://www.wampserver.com/en/ for simple installation of Apache, Mysql, and PHP in one bundle.

Comment: thanks but i need to solve this with my IIS do you know how ?

Comment: try look more information about the error on "event viewer"

Comment: Yes, I also encourage you to use Apache instead of IIS. You are heading down a path through Headache Forest to Frustration Mountain with IIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get **IIS Express** with **Web Platform Installer**. You'll find PHP in the list there and URL Rewrite, PHP WinCache and more utilities. IIS Express is better for local dev than IIS as it's lighter on the permissions that it needs.

Read here [IIS Express vs Default IIS that comes with Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389024/iis-express-vs-default-iis-that-comes-with-windows-7) ... you might have issues this your permissions and that's a major PITA to handle. I always eventually set IIS up properly but can never actually tell what I did :) on the permissions side.

**Apache on Windows is not as fast as IIS.** But if your hosting is Linux, you might want to use it to get acquainted to .htaccess Rewrites and overall rules too.