# How to use IIS Express 10?

Tags: iis, iis-10, iis-express-10

I have installed IIS 10 On my Windows 10 PC but after installation I cannot find the application either in start menu or if I make a search for it.

I have tried to go to `C:\Program files\IIS Express\` but can't understand anything there

I want to see the files of a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to understand the difference between iis and iis express. IIS express would only be used by people who don't have access to IIS or want something that is lighter than IIS but more like IIS than Cassini. IIS 7 ships with the operating system and is tightly integrated to Windows. more information you can refer to this link:

[IIS Express Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview)

[IIS Web Server Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-web-server-overview)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8396060/13336642

If you are installing IIS 10(not iis express), then you can find it in the start menu. If you can’t find it, you may have a problem with the installation. you can refer to the following article on how to install iis. If it is iis express, then you can use it in visual studio.

https://www.howtogeek.com/112455/how-to-install-iis-8-on-windows-8/

[image]